# How can I delete rows from multiple tables with multiple foreign keys?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, key, multiple-columns, sql-delete

I have 4 different tables and I want the user to delete a row in the 4 different tables using a klantid.
This are my tables

1. `Customer` having `customerid`, `name`.
2. `Customercard` having `Cardid`, `customerid(FK)`
3. `booking` having `bookingid`, `customerid`
4. `bookingroom` having `bookingid`

I can delete from 3 tables with filling the 'customerid' in but I also have to delete the row/rows in booking room. How can I delete this for my database?

I've searched on Stack Overflow but all the answers are for a single FK which affects more tables. I have 2 different FK '''(Customerid and Bookingid)'''

Answer (score 0):

You must select the bookingIds of the customer. I don't know exactly your problem, but it seems that you only want to delete everything of this 4 tables, where the customer is assigned.

So you have your customerId = XXX:

```
DELETE FROM bookingroom WHERE bockingid IN (SELECT b.id FROM booking b WHERE customerid = XXX);
```

After this you can delete from the other 3 tables with `WHERE customerId = XXX`

---

**Edit:**
If you want to delete a customer, you must at least delete all rows, where the customer is referenced. That is `Customercard` and `booking`.

If you want to delete also the bookingrooms of all bookings, the customer is referenced, you can use the statement above.

Then you can delete the bookings of the customer:

```
DELETE FROM booking WHERE customerid = XXX;
```

Deleting the Customercards of customer:

```
DELETE FROM Customercard where customerid = XXX;
```

Then you can delte the customer (if he is not assigned by other tables):

```
DELETE FROM Customer WHERE customerid = XXX;
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, no i want to delete a customer but i have to delete all the bookings where the customer ID is used and so all the bookingid's where the customerID is used in.

Comment: See my edit. If you only to delete all bookings, customercards of the customer, you can do it by customerId. If you also want to delete bookingrooms of all bookings of the customer, you can use the query above before deleting the bookings etc.

Comment: You're welcome. Hint: Click the green button to accept the answer (also in your other posts) to let future users know which answer solved the question.;)